# kickstart is frozen at 100%

Tags: centos, kickstart

I'm trying to install CentOS 6.5 into virtualbox using [packer](http://www.packer.io/), but the install screen is freezing at 100%:

[image]

The other consoles are showing the following information:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

(blank screen)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

```
...
07:14:55,644 INFO   : transferring http://10.0.2.2:8081/centos-6.5/ks.cfg
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

```
...
INFO NetworkManager: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

(blank screen)

---

My kickstart config is [here](https://raw2.github.com/opscode/bento/2fd3170ec5d899e9c688ac0f29cae4ff10fad90e/packer/http/centos-6.5/ks.cfg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is your issue but I would change this line:

```
echo "vagrant" | passwd --stdin vagrant
```

To this line:

```
echo -n "vagrant" | passwd vagrant --stdin
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't get that far :(

Comment: Based on where it's stalling and the output from the F3 console it would appear that your ks.cfg file is never even getting retrieved. Are you sure the location is correct? http://10.0.2.2:8081/centos-6.5/ks.cfg?

Comment: The build seems to be working fine on a linux host.  I think it may be an issue with the windows network drivers for virtualbox - which I've had trouble with before.  Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction!